# Seek, Locate, Destroy

Tags: doctor-who, influences, blakes-7

From *Doctor Who* (new) Series 8, Episode 2, "Into the Dalek":

> DALEKS: Seek, locate, destroy. Surrender is not accepted.

And again:

> MORGAN: Fire!
>   DALEK: Exterminate. Advance. Seek, locate, destroy.
>   DALEK 2: Seek, locate, destroy.
>   DALEK 3: Exterminate.

I always assumed that "Seek, locate, destroy" was just a typical Dalekky thing to say, like their second favourite phrase after "Exterminate". Then recently I discovered there's an episode called ["Seek, Locate, Destroy"](http://blakes7.wikia.com/wiki/Seek-Locate-Destroy_(episode)) in the TV series *Blake's Seven*, created by ... Terry Nation, a.k.a. the real-world Davros, a.k.a. the guy who created the Daleks.

**Has the Daleks' "Seek, locate, destroy" ever been acknowledged as a Blake's Seven tribute?**

Comment: It's also a Metallica song.

Comment: The Metallica song is just "Seek and Destroy", FWIW.

Comment: In the original pitch, the Liberator was created by an alien race fighting the Daleks, who would have been introduced as the aliens at the end of Season 2, but plans changed.

Answer (score 9):

Blake's 7 was first broadcast 1978. The Daleks first appeared in 1963.

The first occurance of a Dalek saying "Seek, locate, exterminate" I can find was in Destiny of the Daleks (1979), also written by Nation. There may be an earlier one in the same pattern - I don't have searchable scripts to hand.

Occam's razor would suggest it's **not a tribute**, just that Terry Nation was fond of the phrase in the late '70s. So there would be no particular reason to acknowledge it.

Comment: "The Chase" has "locate, infiltrate, separate, exterminate," first said by a dalek, then much more fluidly by William Hartnell.